# Should I use ViewModels/models in more than one context?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ViewModel called `CompanyListViewModel`. It represents a list of companies in my application. It has a property of type `ObservableCollection<CompanyViewModel>`, to which a ListView binds.

`CompanyListViewModel` has a command called `OpenCommand`. This command opens the selected company in a new window for editing.

The function that `OpenCommand` calls looks like this:

```
public void Open()
{
    Company selectedCompany = SelectedCompanyViewModel.Model
    CompanyViewModel elm = new CompanyViewModel(selectedCompany);
    openHandler(elm); // opens a new window with the given vm.
}
```

So this function:

- Gets the currently selected `CompanyViewModel`
- retrieves the underlying model.
- instantiates a new viewmodel that shares the model of the existing viewmodel.
- opens this viewmodel.

Is this correct? I have two alternatives:

- Open a new window using the existing viewmodel
- Get a new model from the datbase, place it in a new viewmodel, and open a window with this.

Which method should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the functionality your application should have. When changes made to the model have to be present in all where other places the model is used, using the same model seems to be the correct way.

When you want all places the view model is used to immediately show any changes made to the model even if they aren't confirmed by the user you should share your view model.

Opening the new window with a completely different model is an alternative when you want no logical connection between the both instances. Then you have to rely on your business logic that the first model gets replaced when the second one was changed and saved back into database.